# typecasting to custom object - is data lost?

Tags: parameters, casting, base-class

I created a custom UIButton object with an NSInteger property, to which I assign an enum value for identification purposes. I was using the .tag property for something else, so i created a custom class.

I had to pass my custom class to a function that accepts a UIButton as a parameter and returns a UIButton. I simply typecast the button by typing this:

```
self.clockInButton = (PACustomButton *)[self changeButtonImage:(PACustomButton *)self.clockInButton withImage:@"white_square_small"];
```

when i get the button back from the method, will i lose my custom buttonName property? will it conform to UIButton or will it keep the custom properties?

**EDIT**

FYI, im not looking for a solution to any problem. im just asking for informational purposes. as a solution (in my case), i could simply write a new function that did the same thing but was intended for the custom button instead of a basic UIButton. however, if you want to offer alternative solutions, they are welcome. I just want to make sure my original question is answered

Comment: What does changeButtonImage: do?

Comment: changes the background image of a button. for all control states. its a custom method i wrote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast your object to whatever you want. This does not change what the true type of the object is. I can assign my UIButton subclass to a regular UIButton reference, this does NOT turn my subclassed button into something else. The key thing to remember here is the difference between pointers and objects. Just because a pointer is of type X does not mean the object it points to is of type X.

Comment: great answer. i originally came from classic C so this actually means something to me. +1 for pointing out the difference between an object and a pointer